# seed-fu data removing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I try to change data loaded by **seed-fu** in rails project database.
And cant find any standard way to delete rows
**Seed-fu** can:

*1. create new record.*

*2. update existing.*

Is it possible to delete some records.
Database already in production use and we cant simply recreate all data from scratch.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't update or delete with it. Use ActiveRecord to do that.

```
User.find().destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

as the other user you could use normal destroy:

```
User.destroy(id)
```